# Multiple Leaflet TileLayers with extended maxzoom

Tags: leaflet, layers

I've got 2 layers(for indoor and outdoor) in my web application. If i zoom beyond 19, the indoor layer should be displayed and the outdoor layer tiles will be scaled up, because their maxzoom is 19. This works fine with this js-code:

```
map = L.map('full-map');
tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 23,
    maxNativeZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);


var indoorLayer = L.tileLayer("http://" + SERVER_IP + ":8002/tiles/" + 0 + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    minZoom: 20,
    maxZoom: 23
}).addTo(map);
```

Except this is how it looks when i add the indoor layer to the map:
[image]
What makes me wonder is how some outdoor tiles are still displayed.

It works perfectly if i don't add the indoor layer to the map:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!

It could be that your indoor tile layer has no tiles to serve outside your building area. So Leaflet receives a 404 error and displays the Error Tile instead (<strike>or a grey tile if not specified</strike>), therefore covering the outdoor tiles.

You could set up a transparent tile and define its URL in [`errorTileUrl` Tile Layer option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-errortileurl), or use the `L.Util.emptyImageUrl` in that option:

```js
var indoorLayer = L.tileLayer(
    "http://" + SERVER_IP + ":8002/tiles/" + 0 + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    minZoom: 20,
    maxZoom: 23,
    errorTileUrl: L.Util.emptyImageUrl
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This seems logical, the only outdoor tiles that are displayed are in range of the tiles we got for our indoor map. These tiles are transparent. I hoped the not existing tiles are just not displayed.

I've added the option, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: ok we will have to dig further then…

Comment: you were right with your assumption, i've set the opacity of the indoor map to 0.5:
http://postimg.org/image/9gwa1m3t9/

Comment: Strange as actually you were also right: when tile is missing, it should just display nothing, so it should not cover the outdoor tiles… :-S http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/75/

Comment: Any chance your server actually sends a grey tile on requests outside the tiles it knows?

Comment: I will check on that :)

Comment: So i've got a look at the server and it justs sends "arg0.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);" back. (For excuse it was written by the previous project team ;D)  So what should i send to leaflet instead?

Comment: Ok, my problem was, that the original tile generation generated some grey tiles that were not needed. If you got the same problem with maperitive just add the parameter "exclude-partial=true"

Comment: I am glad you finally pin pointed the root cause! Thank you for the feedback.